# Drain trap leaking at compression joint

Tags: plumbing, drain, p-trap

After finally resolving a leak at the connection of the wall tube to the stub out (see the brass waste adapter), I installed a new p-trap to resolve a leak connecting the j-bend to the wall tube. However, the new PVC p-trap leaks at this same spot (see below) as well. I've tried "resetting" it several times. The threads are not crossed. There is no washer (it's built in), but again, it's a p-trap so it should be in good shape.

What am I doing wrong? The leak is very slow. There will be only one or two drops after and hour or so but it seems no matter what I do, I can never get a complete water tight seal. I've only hand tightened, but I've tightened it pretty damn hard for hand tight. Should I take a pipe wrench to it? Is the trap just junk? I realize the flexible traps are frowned upon in the plumbing community but after installing the waste adapter, the rigid trap no longer aligned well with the sink tail pipe.

[image: slip nut leak]

Comment: Yeah, sometimes a bit more than hand-tight is necessary (especially if, like me, you don't have ape hands).

Comment: @isherwood  Fourth generation carpenter and you don't have ape hands???  I don't think so. LOL

Comment: Heh. I'm built like a ballet dancer, man. :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try loosening the chrome nut at the wall and then reset the trap and tighten it up. I know "they" say to hand tighten but if the two pieces don't line up perfectly, then a little help is needed. Give it an extra eighth of a turn with a pair of Chanellocks, making sure you're not cross threaded and then tighten the chrome nut at the wall.

Comment: I agree. Try to support the pipe while you turn so you're not moving it--just the nut.

Comment: The chrome nut isn't where the problem is, that was solved by adding the brass waste adapter which got me in this mess in the first place. That brought the stub out too far to use the old trap, so I got the new flexible one but it is leaking where I drew the blue line on the image. I just tried tightening that nut with my pipe wrench so we'll see if there are any drips in a little while.

Comment: @Andrew  I know the chrome nut isn't the problem but by loosening it, the piece coming out of it might adjust to the trap easier, stopping that leak. Then just tighten the chrome nut back up.

Comment: @JACK ahhh ok. I'm with you now.

Answer (score 2):

It could be because the trap is a flex pipe that the (Not so flexible) accordion section is pulling on the connection that is leaking causing it to not seat properly.

*Could you not get the J-bend pipe far enough into the wall pipe to use a non flexible P-trap* ?

Try wrapping the treads with Teflon tape.

It is normally not need for this application but if the flex pipe is pulling the built in washer out of its seat then having a good seal on the threads may stop the leak.

**+1 for the pink tile**.

Comment: I could *kinda* get the wall tube part of the trap (trap arm?) far enough into the wall pipe to use a non-flexible p-trap, but it put a lot of pressure forward on the tail pipe of the sink which was causing it to leak at the drain.